# Floating action Button vector image remains black (Material design)

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to get the vector image inside a Floating action button (with  @+id/fab )  to be white, however, it keeps showing up as black (the image inside the button)

**The  layout:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- this is the Detail page of the item. -->

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <!--android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!--android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout -->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <!--android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar -->

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!--            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!--android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/item_detail_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:backgroundTint="#0550F7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigation_white_24dp"
        />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the drawable ic_navigation_white_24dp:

```
<vector android:height="50dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="50dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/white" android:pathData="M12,2L4.5,20.29l0.71,0.71L12,18l6.79,3 0.71,-0.71z"/>
</vector>
```

the theme for this activity (in androidManifest.xml) is:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

ideas how to make the vectore image color of "ic_navigation_white_24dp" white ?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post a picture of the image (or a screenshot)  Also, what is the API version of the device you are running this on?  The usual way I've seen to specify the color of the image is to use "android:fillColor" in the xml file for the vector so it seems like you're doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check your vector drawable in android studio preview tab**

Is it draw correctly? Preview tab is right at the IDE.

You can see how xml drawables are shown

**2. Adjust Background of Floating Action Button**

**3. Can you adjust your vector drawable size to 24x24?**

Comment: 1. it was drawn correctly but the vector itself was black instead of white.
i tried chaning the color inside the drawable it didn't do the trick
background is already what i defined - thew issue was with the vector image itself

i ended up using the answer from the original answer (my question turned out to be duplicate).

In the fab element I added this row: 


app:tint="@null"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "android:tint="#FFFFFF" attribute from the vector drawable, and the " app:backgroundTint="#0550F7" from the layout.